# Multiple non-hierarchical custom taxonomies frequently used terms showing up in first selected taxonomy box

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm using WordPress 4.9.8, and I'm declaring multiple non-hierarchical custom taxonomies to use on a post type called "inventory".  The non-hierarchical custom post types use the tag cloud style interface in the Wordpress backend for content editors to categorize inventory.  When I click on "Choose from the most used tags" in one of the custom taxonomy boxes it loads the tag cloud as expected.  But when I click on "Choose from the most used tags" in a second custom taxonomy box, the tag cloud loads in the first custom taxonomy box.  Is there a way to fix this?  Or, is there another interface I can use to access the custom taxonomy terms other than the tag cloud?  I want to keep the taxonomies non-hierarchical.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Please explain what are first and second taxonomy boxes. Why and how do you have two of them?

Comment: I have multiple taxonomies for the post type.  One is called Type.  One is called Model.  One is called Make.  So there are three taxonomy boxes for this custom post type.  So for example, if I click on "Choose from the most used tags" in Type, I will see the most commonly used terms of Type.  If I go to Model and click "Choose from the most used tags" there, the most commonly used terms of Model will appear in the box for Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that serves my purposes.  I found this plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/) that will allow me to use Radio Buttons for taxonomies instead of the tag cloud, so I avoid the bug with the tag cloud by using this interface instead.  It only allows posts to be tagged with one term from each taxonomy at a time but that is fine for my case.